# How to keep section titles together with the content in ConTeXt?

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking, context, context-mkiv

I found many places in my document where the subsection titles are places alone at the bottom of the page with the content on the next page, like this:

```
 ____________ ____________
|            |            |
| Section    | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| Section    | .......... |
|____________|____________|
```

I do not want any section titles to appear without any text below them, e.g., this will be fine:

```
 ____________ ____________
|            |            |
| Section    | Section    |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
| .......... | .......... |
|            | .......... |
|____________|____________|
```

- I used `\startsubsection` and `\stopsubsection` to define the whole section text.

Is there any way to make sure that the section titles always appear together with at least one line of text from the paragraph inside?

Comment: +1 This always bugs the heck out of me.  I've been known to write fluff or be the most vicious editor simply to avoid such eyesores.  What's being asked for is something like a `~` for `\par`.  (Is there a `\par*`?)

Comment: Normally section titles have some penaty after them to prevent orphans, so it is hard to say why you are seeing this behavior. The usual way to prevent a page break after a section heading is to use `after={\page[none]}`. If that doesn't work try `before={\testpage[3]}`

Comment: There’s also [``\page[preference]``](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/page). Normally, it does a ``\testpage[3]`` but also comes with special handling for columns.

Comment: @Village: Can you provide a minimal example that demostrate's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `\clubpenalty = 10000` in preamble? It removes single lines of paragraphs on the preceding page (see [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/TeX/penalty)). Not sure if this is why I never get your problem, or whether it is just a coincidence, though!

Comment: With an infinite `\clubpenalty` you're in for some really bad pagebreaks.